# Ionic Cordova Post method not working

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, visual-studio-code

I am new in Hybrid application development. I am using Ionic cordova to build my application. I am trying to call post method with in my application.

```
var url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/XXXX";
var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append("Accept",'application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
   let options = new RequestOptions({headers : headers});

   let postParams = {
     Name: this.imagename,
     StartDate: this.adstartdate,
     EndDate: this.adEnddate,
     UploadName:this.imagename
  }
```

// above code(postParams) is not getting attached with below code.

```
 this.http.post(url,postParams,options)
 .subscribe(data =>{
   console.log(data['_body']);
   alert('Sucess Enter'+ data['_body']);
   this.jsonvalue = JSON.stringify(data['_body']);


    alert('Json Value : '+ this.jsonvalue);

 },error =>{

   console.log(error);
   alert('Fail');
 }
```

I want to know were I am doing wrong in this code.
Please ignore my grammatical mistakes.

Comment: Have you got any error or error code like 500 or 404?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error code.

Comment: @hrdkisback  am able to hit the api but, but am not able to attach the headers

Comment: where are you setting the fields of `postParams`?

Comment: @suraj 

     let postParams = {
     Name: this.imagename,
     StartDate: this.adstartdate,
     EndDate: this.adEnddate,
     UploadName:this.imagename
  }

where Key for API:
Name,StartDate,EndDate,UploadName

Comment: did you log those properties?

Comment: @suraj yes, I did ,and getting the values on that key.But its not getting attach with api

Comment: how are you retrieving in server side?

Comment: @suraj 
using Post Method, I have try my api with Advance Restapi client  it is working there.

Comment: you mentioned before you cant receive headers.. you know that you are setting as body?

Comment: ok sir,
please help me how i can resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send RequestOptions object as param for post method.

**example**:

```
import {RequestOptions} from '@angular/http'
```

then

```
    let opt1 = new RequestOptions({
               Name: this.imagename,
               StartDate: this.adstartdate,
               EndDate: this.adEnddate,
               UploadName:this.imagename
               });
```

use the above opt for http request

```
this.http.post(url,postParams,opt) //here
 .subscribe(data =>{
   console.log(data['_body']);
   alert('Sucess Enter'+ data['_body']);
   this.jsonvalue = JSON.stringify(data['_body']);


    alert('Json Value : '+ this.jsonvalue);

 },error =>{

   console.log(error);
   alert('Fail');
 }
```